# Kubera's soldiers (in the Mahabharata) claiming the world to be 'asatya', etc

Tags: bhima, kubera

In the Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya, Madhvacharya says the following:

तत्रापरांश्चैव बहूनसत्यं निरीश्वरं चाप्रतिष्ठं च लोकम् ।
सिद्धोऽहमीशोऽहमिति ब्रुवाणान् गुणान् विष्णोः ख्यापयन् वादतोऽजैत् । २२.२८४ । [22.301]
भिन्नं विष्णुमधिकं सर्वतश्च ब्रुवन् प्रवीरान् लक्षमेषां निजघ्ने ।

In the battle that erupted at the Saugandhikavana between the soldiers of Kubera and Bhima, the above verses say: There were many others who proclaimed 'the world is asatya, without Ishwara, without any pratishTha, basis, I am accomplished, I am Isha (Ishwara), .. Bhima debated with them and vanquished them all and saying 'Vishnu is different and greater than all' he killed several hundreds of them.'

The commentary cites the Bhagavadgita 16th chapter verses that bring out the thinking of aasura-natured people.  One can read the verses here:  https://hindi.webdunia.com/religion/religion/hindu/geeta/Chapter16_6-20.htm

The chapter concerning the Saugandhika incident in the Mahabharata is 3.155.

https://sa.wikisource.org/s/1za  - In this chapter from verse 3.155.10 onward is the description of the combat of Bhima with the soldiers of Kubera.

https://bombay.indology.info/mahabharata/text/UD/MBh03.txt  This is the complete parva wherein occurs the above chapter 155.

The question is: Where in that chapter does the stated incident occur? The chapter no doubt reports that Bhima killed many opponents in that battle. But the debate on the 'asatyam apratiShTham nirIshvaram, siddho'ham...etc.' does not appear in the Mahabharata chapter either explicitly or implicitly.

Does the Mahabharata report anywhere that Kubera's soldiers claimed the world to be 'asatya', etc. and that Bhima debated with them and finally killed them?

Comment: It's not found in the [Southern Recension of Mahabharata](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mahabharata-sarit.html) also. You can try reading the notes attached to the BORI Critical Edition [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.486384/page/n509/mode/2up). It's possible Madhvacharya was commenting on a modified copy/manuscript.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link to the BORI critical edition.  I went through the notes attached in those pages and did not find anything that adds to the verses.

Comment: Well, if you can't find it even in the notes to CE, it must be a very late interpolation and not worth taking seriously. The [Editorial Note](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.486384/page/n7/mode/2up) says the CE was prepared by consulting 28 different manuscripts.

Comment: Here's a better scan of the same chapter from CE: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.485488/page/n543/mode/2up. And the [Appendix](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.485490/page/n553/mode/2up) which lists additional passages/verses from various manuscripts.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts.  I could read the better scan and the contents of the link to the appendix of additional pages. However, there is no reference in those pages to what I am looking for.

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=KyGADwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT903&dq=%22%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%82%20%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%82%22&pg=PT903#v=twopage&q&f=false) quotes Madhvacharya's commentary following Chapter 150 but the verses you are looking for are missing from the chapter. All this goes to prove the Madhvacharya's references are not authentic and he was probably quoting from a tampered manuscript not older than 1-2 generations before him.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually that edition of the Mahabharata was very recently published by a Madhva Mutt in Udupi, by labeling it 'vaishnava paaTha'.  They have also mentioned there that 'what is //attested// by Madhva in that 'Tatparya Nirnaya' and Sri Vadiraja in his 'Lakshalankara' (a selective commentary on the MB), alone is considered 'authentic' by the publishers. Also, the 'Tatparya Nirnaya' of Madhva is not really a commentary of the MB but an 'arriving at the purport of the MB' as Madhva sees the MB.

Comment: So Madhvacharya was using a bit of his imagination in Tatparya Nirnaya?

Comment: One can come to one's own conclusion.